# Looking for the simplest way to get elevation for a give wgs84 coordinate

Tags: java, geotools, elevation

I started a project and write an application in java using geotools. I have an simple geoobject with the attributes latitude, longitude and altitude. Now i have to determine, wheather the geoobject is an aircraft or a car on a road.

I modeled my roads as LineStrings an my geoobjects a circle polygones. So i run a simple test, if the geoobject touchs or intersects the linestring, at the given coordinate. So far it works.

But some roads have an elevation. I found sample digital elevation model files, but don't know to handle them. Is there an easy way to get elevation data respectively is there another simple way? Need i software like postgis or somethin else?

Answer (score 5):

You can download elevation data in raster format from [this url](http://dwtkns.com/srtm/)

Load each tif into postgres with:-

```
 raster2pgsql -d -s 4326 -t 50x50 <TIFF>.tif <YOUR TABLE> | psql -n <YOUR DATABASE>
```

Then get an elevation with:-

```
SELECT ST_Value(rast,1, 
                ST_GEOMFROMEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT('||lon||' '||lat||')')
               )
```

This abstracts most of the geometry stuff for you. You will need gdal, a postgres database with postgis installed and a connection from java.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) [image tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/raster/image.html) to show you how to load a raster (which is what your DEM is)

```
    AbstractGridFormat format = GridFormatFinder.findFormat( rasterFile ); 
    //this is a bit hacky but does make more geotiffs work
    Hints hints = new Hints();
    if (format instanceof GeoTiffFormat) {
        hints = new Hints(Hints.FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER, Boolean.TRUE);
    }
    reader = format.getReader(rasterFile, hints);
    Layer rasterLayer = new GridReaderLayer(reader, rasterStyle);
```

You can use the `evaluate` methods on the coverage to get back the raster value(s) at a point.